# Are  Adjectives Sometimes  "Stem-Changing"?

Tags: grammar

Most people that study German learn about "stem-changing VERBs (z.B. singen, sang, gesungen).

I don't come across them often, but there appear to be stem-changing adjectives, as well.
Example: Gross= great. But Friedrich der Grösse.

Are there "classes" of such adjectives (e.g. for words with a, o, or u)? Or a handful of individual cases? Or am I seeing something that doesn't actually exist?

Comment: It's "Friedrich der Große".

Comment: It is Friedrich der _Große_, not der _Größe_. However, you say _größer_ (greater).

Comment: So the stem change is in the COMPARATIVE of adjectives (e.g lang, länger, usw.)

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that's right. Maybe it's best if you edit your question accordingly.

Comment: In groß vs. größer the vowel is substituted by an umlaut. A change in the stem would require an ablaut, as in singen vs. gesungen. Compare ablaut vs. umlaut.

Comment: Where did you find 'Friedrich der Grösse' - it's just wrong!

Comment: I need a specification: Are you looking for adjectives in comparisons with different "stems"?

Comment: @user unknown: spoken by one of my German-American friends. We're prone to making such mistakes.

Comment: Well - see the comment of eowyn. If you don't have an example, what is your question, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started a list, but I'm not sure it it's finished:

- alt - älter - am ältesten [english: old]
- arm  - ärmer - am ärmsten [english: poor]
- groß - größer - am größten [english: huge]
- jung - jünger - am jüngsten [english: young]
- kalt - kälter - am kältesten [english: cold]
- klug - klüger - am klügsteen [english: smart]
- kurz - kürzer - am kürzesten [english: short]
- lang - länger - am längsten [english: long]
- dumm - dümmer - am dümmsten [english: stupid]
- gesund - gesünder - am gesündesten [english: healthy]
- grob - gröber - am gröbsten [english: crude]
- hart - härter - am härtesten [english: hard]
- krank - kränker - am kränkesten [english: sick]
- rot - röter - am rötesten [english: red]
- scharf - schärfer - am schärfsten [english: spicy/hot]
- stark - stärker - am stärksten [english: strong]
- schwach - schwächer - am schwächsten [english: weak]
- warm - wärmer - am wärmsten [english: warm]

---

- dunkel - dunkler - am dunkelsten [english: dark]
- edel - edler - am edelsten [english: noble]
- gern - lieber - am liebsten [english: gladly]
- gut - besser - am besten [english: good]
- hoch - höher - am höchsten [english: high]
- nah - näher - am nächsten [english: near]
- teuer - teurer - am teuersten [english: expensive]
- viel / sehr - mehr - am meisten [english: very]

You see, in the first list it's often a change from vocal to a "umlaut" (ä,ü,ö)
The 2nd list is totally irregular.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "compendium" of answers given by others (mainly in comments).

Adjectives sometimes do change the vowel in the stem in the comparative or superlative forms. 
e.g. *groß — größer — am größten* [English: *big*].

They *don't* change the stem between masculine, feminine, and neuter forms.

So *groß* and *Friedrich der Größe* was a wrong example.

But it led to a correct one.