# What is an “Ablaut”?

Tags: terminology, conjugation, vowel

My understanding is that *Umlaut* represents the diacritical marks over *a, o, u,* etc.

But what is an *Ablaut?*

The topic came up in the comments on [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/are-adjectives-sometimes-stem-changing).

Comment: "Umlaut" has two meanings: it could be the diacritical mark, or the change of vowel sound (e.g. foot->feet). Also, see Wikipedia's [Ablaut vs. umlaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablaut#Ablaut_versus_umlaut).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Ablaut"* is a linguistic term symonymous to *apophony*:

> A  vowel change, characteristic of Indo-European languages, that accompanies a change in grammatical function; for example, i, a, u in sing, sang, sung.<sup>[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ablaut)</sup>

The term was first introduced by Jacob Grimm who defines it as follows:

> ABLAUT, m. *permutatio vocalium literarum*, geregelter übergang des vocals der wurzel in einen andern; ein edles und ihr wesentliches vermögen der deutschen sprache, verschieden von umlaut.<sup>[Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm](http://dwb.uni-trier.de/)</sup>

Examples in German woud be:

> singen, sang, gesungen
>   stehe, stand, gestanden
>   reissen, riss, gerissen

Comment: What is the difference between foot-feet (umlaut) and singen-sang (ablaut)?

Comment: @Tim N. My guess is that the difference between "foot-feet" are represented by an umlaut only in GERMAN. Meaning that they would probably be "ablauts" in English.

Comment: @Tom: In the Wikipedia article, the vowel change between the _English_ words "foot" and "feet" is listed as an umlaut (the change of sound, not the diacritic).

Comment: @Tim: I answered your question here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/whats-the-difference-between-umlaut-and-ablaut/9426#9426 (it was a bit long for a comment).